# Python running requests for same url in multithread

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, urllib3

I want to send multithread request of same url with different parameters inside an async program. Currently my code is something like below:

```
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession
import asyncio

async def main():
    session = FuturesSession(max_workers=100)

    params = ['foo{}'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]

    url = 'some_host'

    async def send_request(param):
        f = session.get(url, params={'param': param})

        t = asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.wrap_future(f))

        r = await t

        # check t is the request you expected, for example check that if you 
        # request for foo1 you are receiving foo1 object, but sometimes
        # returns value for different parameters                                                                                                                                

        return r

    tasks = []

    for param in params:
        tasks.append(
            asyncio.ensure_future(send_request(param))
        )

    await asyncio.wait(tasks,
                       return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED)
```

As for example [this link](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/#:%7E:text=Unfortunately%20requests.,Queue%20from%20Python%27s%20queue%20module.) stated, requests session is not thread-safe, but by examining the code of requests I found that even by creating a session for each thread or even creating a session for each request still it could be possible that for a same url threading causes problem, because of this part of code:

```
conn = self.poolmanager.connection_from_url(url)
```

This line is from `requests` module(from function `get_connection` of file `adapters.py`) which uses `poolmanager` of `urllib` and returns connection for a url, I think that this part causes that request for same url with different parameters return responses unrelated to the requested parameter.

After some search I found [futures_requests](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) which seemed to solve this problem but still exists. I am still looking for a solution to able to use multithread request inside an async program.

Comment: Why use threads? Why not use an asyncio-aware library like aiohttp instead?

Comment: I am using `httpx` for async request, but it has some defect because it uses one thread it could not generate the volume that I need to generate or maybe I am using it wrong.

Comment: asyncio is single threaded. If you’re actually butting up against its limits and need to move to something else like threads, you’re probably better ditching asyncio completely and just using threads.

Comment: I do not think this problem related to asyncio, if instead of asyncio I had a sync program there were no difference in the threading problem that I mentioned. I have written a code that is completely based on `asyncio` but for generating enough amount of requests I needed a thread solution to send requests. But I think the problem is related to `requests` and `urllib` not just `asyncio` and using thread inside it.